# document.getElementById() not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen other posts with the same title. 
[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) does not apply.
I am not looking for the ID before the html is loaded. Here is the whole file:

https://jsfiddle.net/2uxqmsth/
If you click on the link - the function is called.
The relevant javascript is below:

```
    function getNewComment() {
        var xd = document.getElementById('#xdialog');

        if ( xd === null ) alert( 33 );
        else alert( 22 );
    }
```

Comment: dont youse # in id

Comment: `getElementById('xdialog')` not `getElementById('#xdialog')`

Comment: Thanks all. have not use js in a while... I deserve -1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) — _“[…] `document.querySelector('#elementID')`, as opposed to the method by which an element is retrieved by its `id` under `document.getElementById('elementID')`; in the first the `#` character is essential, **in the second it would lead to the element not being retrieved.**”_ (emphasis mine) — already answered by the second answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing javascript with JQuery.

If you want to use javascript then it will be

```
var xd = document.getElementById('xdialog');
```

and not

```
var xd = document.getElementById('#xdialog');
```

If you want to use Jquery,then use like this:-

```
var xd = $("#xdialog");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var xd = document.getElementById('#xdialog');
```

change this to

```
 var xd = document.getElementById('xdialog');
```

Comment: I meant it for while selecting ids

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` takes an ID, not a selector.

Your ID doesn't have a `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following documentation for [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

You'll need to remove the `#` from your [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id), so your snippet should instead look like the following:

```
function getNewComment() {
  var xd = document.getElementById('xdialog');

  if ( xd === null ) alert( 33 );
  else alert( 22 );
}
```